# How do I sort a dataframe column alphabetically starting with the letter "l"?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I would like to sort alphabetically beginning with the letter "l" (rather than "a").

Here's my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['C:/folder/!!file this', 15], ['C:/folder/apple', 14], ['C:/folder/Land file', 10]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Doc', 'Size'])
```

Here's what I want my dataframe to look like:

```
data = [['C:/folder/Land file', 10], ['C:/folder/!!file this', 15], ['C:/folder/apple', 14]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Doc', 'Size'])
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
alphabet = """lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijk!"#$%_'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^&`{|}~"""
    
df = df.sort_values(by=['Doc'], key=lambda x: [
        alphabet.index(c) for c in x[0]])
```

I get the error code `ValueError: substring not found.`

I also tried the following, but it doesn't change the order in the dataset:

```
def split(word):
    return list(word)


mylist = split(
    """lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijk!"#$%_'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^&`{|}~""")


alphabetical = pd.Categorical(mylist,
                              ordered=True)

df = df.sort_index(level=alphabetical)
print(df)
```

Comment: Do you only have the characters from the shown set?

Comment: You could use pandas' `str.translate` method to map `mylist` characters to characters ordered by ASCII values and use the resulting series as key for sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact logic is unclear, but one option is to use a translation table to reorder the priority of the characters:

```
# original priority
alphabet  = """!abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"""
# new priority
alphabet2 = """lmnopqrstuvwxyz!abcdefghijk"""

t = str.maketrans(alphabet2, alphabet)

df.sort_values('Doc', key=lambda s: s.str.lower().str.translate(t))
```

Output:

```
                     Doc  Size
2    C:/folder/Land file    10
0  C:/folder/!!file this    15
1        C:/folder/apple    14
```

Intermediate translation:

```
0    r:/uc!stf/ooux!t hwxg
1          r:/uc!stf/pdd!t
2      r:/uc!stf/!pbs ux!t
Name: Doc, dtype: object
```

If you only want to consider the first letter of the file name as special and keep normal order of the letter for the rest, use [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
order = np.lexsort([df['Doc'], ~df['Doc'].str.extract('/([^/]+)$', expand=False).str[0].isin(['l', 'L'])])

out = df.iloc[order]
```

Output:

```
                     Doc  Size
2    C:/folder/Land file    10
0  C:/folder/!!file this    15
1        C:/folder/apple    14
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? all your ['Doc'] start with same letter "C"
you might want to split and extract filename before you do
this sorting? like df['filename']=df['doc'].apply(lambda x: x.split['/'][-1]

```
alphabet = """lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijk!"#$%_'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^&`{|}~"""
    
df['ix']=df['doc'].apply(lambda x:alphabet.find(x[0]))
df=df.sort_values(by=['ix'])
df.drop(['ix'], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Hi jsn!  thank you for trying to help.  To answer your question: yes, items in my ['Doc'] column starts with c, but I hope the code will consider the whole path when sorting (just like in a normal sort).  When I run your code, I get `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

Comment: thanks again jsn.  Just so you know, your edited answer doesn't work when I change `C://folder/!! file this` to `C:/folder/file this` (and it should - f follows a)

Comment: i think you will have to revisit how you want to sort your files. this is a per your plan of sorting according to order in  ` alphabet="""lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijk!""" `